# LINQ Query not returning actual values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I'm trying to use LINQ to compare what a user enters in a search bar against a table.

```
 public ActionResult GetLibrary(string searchString, string lib)
    {
        var libraries = Database.Session.Query<Library>().ToArray();

        string searchedLib = (from l in libraries
                              where l.CR_Name.Contains(searchString)
                              select new Library()
                              {
                                  CR_Name = l.CR_Name
                              }).ToString();

        lib = searchedLib;

        return RedirectToAction(actionName: "GetLibInfo",
            controllerName: "Home",
            routeValues: new { lib });
    }
```

Instead of returning an actual value, the query is returning this instead:
     "System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectArrayIterator'2[Models.ModelName,       Models.ModelName]"

Comment: Why are you calling `ToString`?  That's your problem.

Comment: It's not actually. OP would still have an `IEnumerable` instead of a single result. Though you're right, you should avoid calling `ToString()` on a collection

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That `WhereSelectArrayIterator` is an `IEnumerable` representing a set of results. If you only want/expect one "row," use `Single()` or `First()`.

```
var searchedLib = (from l in libraries
                      where l.CR_Name.Contains(searchString)
                      select l).First();

var name = searchedLib.CR_Name;
```

The simplest way:

```
var name = libraries.First(l => l.CR_Name.Contains(searchString)).CR_Name
```

Comment: When try to use Single() or First(), I get an error message saying: Cannot implicitly convert type 'ModelName' to string.

Comment: @bongo700 example provided.

Comment: You need to replace the `select new Library` with simply `select l.CR_Name`.

Comment: Yeah you can do that too. Depends on if you need that library.

Comment: Agreed.  Though, with the `string searchedLib` declaration, it won't work as written.  Need either `var searchedLib` or `select l.CR_Name`.

Comment: @MikeGuthrie also, using `First` or `Single` like above is prone to `NullReferenceException`

Comment: @DPac sometimes you want that.

Comment: @DPac Found one of my aggravations.  `First`/`Single` won't raise a `NullReferenceException` but rather raises an exception that "sequence contains no elements" or such.  What I see _far_ too often is people using `FirstOrDefault`/`SingleOrDefault` and then calling a property on the result, at which point you _do_ get the `NullReferenceException` and have concealed the fact that your query returned no results.  So, only do that if you enjoy making your code harder to debug.

Comment: @MikeGuthrie couldn't agree more. Or you just keep passing the object reference on and on and then check for null at some point by which time the object could have been set to null for a countless number of reasons.